# React enzyme unit test error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have the following basic test:

```
/*eslint-disable */
import LocationChooserStore from './../LocationChooserStore';

describe('AccountStore', () => {
    it('should do', function(){
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    })
})
```

seupTests.js

```
/* eslint-disable */

// =========== ENZYME CONFIG FOR REACT 16 ============== //
import React            from 'react';
import Enzyme           from 'enzyme/build/index';
import EnzymeAdapterReact16 from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new EnzymeAdapterReact16() });
// ===================================================== //

import { I18nextProvider, translate } from 'react-i18next';
import createI18n                     from 'i18n.js';


const localStorageMock = {
    getItem: jest.fn(),
    setItem: jest.fn(),
    clear: jest.fn()
};
global.localStorage    = localStorageMock;

const createTranslation = async () => {
    console.log('1=======================');
    const i18n = await createI18n();
    return i18n;
};

const initTranslation = async function () {
    // This line is commented out only for the LocationDetails.test.js
    // Uncomment it back
    // global.i18n = await createTranslation();

    // global.i18n = {t: ()=>{}};
    // console.log(global.i18n);
};

initTranslation();
```

when I run:

```
npm run js-test src/stores/tests/LocationChooserStore.test.js
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I have been trying to look for solution especially on Github but nothing has worked so far for me.

Comment: By this much detail is is not possible to figure out what the issue is in your code.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I will provide more details...

Comment: There might be a problem in your LocationChooseStore.js file. Try to remove the import of this file from your first test and try again.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html) you need to install [raf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raf) package. (don't forget to import it in your app).

Another way to do it youself as described [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4545#issuecomment-333004504)